# how to import Excel document with multiline rows into SQL?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, ms-office

I want to import my Excel workbook with single worksheet into SQL server, but after trying Import and Export Data I found a problem with my source document. My excel document is multilined, so when I trying to import that wizard wants to imports each row in each column but I want to import my data with IDs and insert every rows with single ID in once columns.
How can I do this?

please look at my sample picture, hope helpful for understanding what I want to do.
[excel to sql problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIe27.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

with bcp we can insert data intotables  use the following queries
`exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp MyTasks.dbo.emp out d:\f\yes.xls -T -c   -U  nagababu -P Test123 '
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM MyTasks.dbo.emp" queryout d:\f\PersonData_n.xls -c -S (local) -T -L 1'
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp MyTasks.dbo.emp format nul -c -t, -f d:\f\EmployeeData_n.xls -S (local)   -T'`

 we have to use in instead of out while importing data from sheet to table 

 use it to import daata to table 
    `exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp MyTasks.dbo.emp in d:\f\yes.xls -T -c   -U  nagababu -P Test123 '`

Comment: I want to import excel data into SQL. your queries usable for exporting from SQL into excel format.

Comment: yah @evgeniBraverman ive posted a new sentence now just go through that

Answer (score 0):

I would manipulate the excel data to make it database friendly.  To do this, I would add an extra worksheet and copy the data from the first sheet to the new sheet.

Then, since you want IDs in every row in col A, I would change the value in col A (of the new sheet) to a formula that copies the value from the same cell in the first sheet, unless it is blank, in which case, copies the value from the cell above the cell with the formula.

Something like:  `=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A2), A1, Sheet1!A2)`

This will give you a column of IDs with every row having a value.  The Import and Export data process should work happily now.